# Inputting random number via "input" interface

Tags: netlogo

I want to input a random number (50~200) into my function. I can do it via code. However, when I try to make it work on the button of interface, it only output the random number within 50 (I create a input button and type "random 50 +150"). I hope the random number can be generated by the "input button" on the interface.

The "fav" is the entity I want to generate the random number.

Thanks for all the help

[interface](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VpkuB.png)      [input](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DgWwz.png)

`to i.diffusion
   let fav random 50 + 150
   let Y ceiling ( 0.5 * C + 0.23 * D + 0.1 * fav + 0.3)
   print Y`

Comment: Can you show the dialogue for the input box? Generally, this is something I would do with a button (with code like `set fav random 50 + 150`. Input widgets are really for entering things that you want to change

Comment: @JenB Hi, I just edited my post. check the image with clicking the highlighted text. Thank you so much.

Comment: and I have tried the code you said, putting set fav random 50 + 150 into the input box, but it still generates the number between 0 to 49.

Comment: My code was for a button, not an input. They are different. What I want is the image when you edit (or create) the input. That is, we need to see the settings that you used.

Comment: @JenB Thank you. I have attached the screen shots. I am not if these pictures are the images you need, but hope you can take a look. Many thanks

Comment: look at your input link - you have it set as receiving a number

Answer (score 2):

Got an idea suddenly.

set the input type to string (command), then let a variable runresult the input.
This seems to work as fine.
Thank you. @JenB

```
to o.diffusion ;; the retweet of an official tweet
  let aaa runresult test   
  let Y ceiling ( 0.5 * A + 0.23 * B + 0.1 * aaa + 0.3)
```